# Hystrix getting access to the current execution state within fallback

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix

I successfully configured `spring-cloud` (via `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix`) to wrap a call to a service.

This all works fine and looks like the following:

```java
@Component
public class MyService {

  @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback")
  public void longRunning() {
     // this could fail
  }

  public void fallback() {
    // fallback code
  }
}
```

My question now is, I would like to log some statistics about the execution error in `longRunning()`

Trying to access `HystrixRequestLog.getCurrentRequest()` within the fallback method throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext() must be called at the beginning of each request before RequestVariable functionality can be used.

I am looking for a simple way to log the exception of `longRunning` if the fallback is called.

testing with `v1.0.0.RC2`

Comment: Did you try just enabling DEBUG logging in `com.netflix.hystrix`?

Comment: Adding the logging did the trick - the full stack trace of longRunning is now reported - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a stack trace you can just enable DEBUG logging in `com.netflix.hystrix`.

As far as I can tell, to use the `HystrixRequestContext` the caller of `MyService` has to call `HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext()` before using the service. That sucks, so if anyone has a better idea, I'm interested.

Comment: Sounds a little cumbersome to me too, would be interesting if there are nicer ways to log errors to make it easier to find out what went wrong in production...

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Javanica v1.4.21, it allows fallback method to have an argument of Throwable type for accessing the command execution exception like so:

```
public void fallback(Throwable e) {
   // fallback code
   LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

To get this feature, your build config needs to override the older version of Javanica pulled in by Spring Cloud.