# spring-cloud-gateway with hystrix fallback, how can I get exception detail?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have config the spring cloud gateway hystrix as below:

```
default-filters:
-   name: Hystrix
    args:
        name: defaultGatewayCommand
        fallbackUri: forward:/hystrix-fallback
```

The problem is, for example, when I throw ResponseStatusException exception in my project, the hystrix fallback will be triggered.

```
@GetMapping("/hystrix-fallback")
public Mono<ApiErrorResponse> hystrixFallback() {
    return Mono.just(new ApiErrorResponse("xxxxxxxx"));
}
```

I want to catch some error info and build my new ApiErrorResponse, but i don 't how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830654/get-failure-exception-in-hystrixcommand-fallback-method

Comment: thank you for your help, but I think this can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

@GetMapping("/hystrix-fallback")
public Mono hystrixFallback(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    Exception exception = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.HYSTRIX_EXECUTION_EXCEPTION_ATTR);
    return Mono.just(new ApiErrorResponse("xxxxxxxx"));
}